# Use the tikz package to plot two overlapping, semi-transparent circles with labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I need to produce something similar to this with latex [image]

I am not familiar at all with the tikz package. However I was able to find a code that I think could be adapted to fit with my needs:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75][thick]
   \draw (0,0) circle (2cm);
   \draw (3,-1) circle (2.5cm);
   \draw (0,0) node {A};
   \draw (3.2,-1) node {B};
   \draw [clip](0,0) circle (2cm);
   \fill[yellow] (3,-1) circle (2.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It produces this figure:
[image]

Does anybody have an idea of how I could adapt the above code to get what I want?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The source code was found at http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=9937

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It's better to include the full code in he question rather  than posting a link. A LaTeX MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Answer (score 5):

No need to clip; you can use `fill opacity`. Start with:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick]
    \draw [fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.5] (0,0) circle (2cm);
    \draw [fill=orange, fill opacity=0.5] (3,-1) circle (2.5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: composing opacities]

and the rest of the thing is a bit of geometry and maybe the `intersections` library:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    thick]
    \draw [fill=cyan, fill opacity=0.5, name path=c1] (0,0) circle (2cm);
    \draw [fill=orange, fill opacity=0.5, name path=c2] (3,-1) circle (2.5cm);
    \draw (0,0) ++(120:2cm) -- ++(120:2.2cm) node [fill=white,inner sep=5pt](a){a};
    \draw (3, -1) ++(30:2.5cm) -- ++(30:2.6cm) node [fill=white,inner sep=5pt](b){b};
    \path [name intersections={of=c1 and c2,by=cs}];
    \draw (cs) -- ++(.5,1) node [fill=white,inner sep=5pt](c){c};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: with labels]

...I leave the rectangles in the legend as an exercise.